# Nested columns containing images are overlapping

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Referencing the image below, I do not understand why the images are overlapping. I have tried to reduce the image dimensions as well as use `class="img-responsive"`. Adjacent to the column described by the code below is another `col-md-6`. Both `col-md-6` are contained within a row.

```
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        When a user long presses on a cell, they will be presented an alert allowing them to either
                        edit the name of a given item, delete the item, or cancel the alert:
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <img src="images/ListMakeriOS/edit_or_cancel.png" alt="Initial long press dialog" width="300px">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <img src="images/ListMakeriOS/edit.png" alt="Edit option selected after long press"
                            width="300px">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to me also. `.img-responsive` is now `.img-fluid` in bs4+

I would remove the `width="300px"` which is wrong syntax anyway.

BTW, maybe you need to use `.col-md-6` instead of `.col-md-3` if you want the images to split evenly.